# uiresume (gcbf) worked in the function, but failed when the function being called

Tags: function, user-interface, callback, batch-processing, matlab-figure

I want to let the user select multiple ROI's on a picture. I used a while loop. I paused and let the user select an ROI. After that the while loop would continue unless the user clicked another button on the toolbar to terminate the while loop. The code worked on single pictures. I made the code a function. When I looped and called the function in another script, it failed to proceed. I pressed Ctrl + C and it showed that "Operation terminated by user during uiwait". Apparently the uiresume didn't work. 
Please let me know where the problems are. Thanks! My code:

```
% Below was basically a copy of the example given in R2014a.
% It created an interactive toolbar with 2 pushbuttons.
fh  = figure('ToolBar', 'none'); hold on;
h_im = imshow(rgb2gray (I));
tbh = uitoolbar(fh);
[X_OK, map_OK] = imread(fullfile(matlabroot,...
    'toolbox','matlab','icons','greenarrowicon.gif'));
[X_rect, map_rect] = imread(fullfile(matlabroot,...
    'toolbox','matlab','icons','tool_rectangle.gif'));
% Convert indexed image and colormap to truecolor
icon_OK = ind2rgb(X_OK, map_OK);
icon_rect = ind2rgb(X_rect, map_rect);
% Create 2 uipushtools in the toolbar
% I introduced 2 variables, leave and draw, to facilitate the control of the
% later while-loop.
pth_OK = uipushtool(tbh, 'CData',icon_OK,...
    'TooltipString','Toolbar push button',...
    'ClickedCallback',...
    'leave = 1; uiresume (gcbf)');
pth_rect = uipushtool(tbh, 'CData',icon_rect, 'Separator','on',...
    'TooltipString','Toolbar push button',...
    'ClickedCallback',...
    'draw = 1; uiresume (gcbf)');

% The loop for ROI selection.
ii = 1;
% Maximum the use can select 30 ROI's.
while ii < 31;
    draw = 0;
    uiwait;
    if leave == 1;
        % If the user pressed "OK" button, leave will be 1.
        break;
    end;
    if draw == 1;
         % If the user pressed the "rect" button, draw will be 1.
        h = imrect;
        wait (h);
        gui_Mask = createMask(h, h_im);
        greyImg (~gui_Mask) = 255;
        ii = ii + 1;
        continue;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw someone used set/waitfor instead.
I tried to change to set/waitfor. Now it works both in the function and when the function being called. 
But I still want to know why uiresume didn't work.